# Can a browser on the client side add JavaScript on our website?

Tags: javascript, android

Can any client add his JavaScript on my website?

Comment: In general yes, but it depends on the client... [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)) cannot even execute JavaScript.

Comment: open developer tools of your favorite browser, open immediate/watch window, enter desired javascript and execute.

Comment: You mean a client can edit source, no.. not directly that is. Oh! i forgot, injection in the console, the address bar, links, bookmarked scripts - all are entrypoints for injection. These injected scripts don't persist (not saved) unless you got a big XSS hole (no pun intended) in your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can inject it into their own browser's view of your site (through all sorts of different methods including using a proxy server to rewrite it, typing it directly into the browser's JS console, and using extensions such as greasemonkey).

They can't inject it into your site for other people to see unless you have an [XSS vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) in your code.

Comment: But as i know this happens in android programming.. can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 2):

Well you won't see it on your end,  but the user can manipulate anything on the client side as long as they have the proper tools.

For example I can change some text in your question easily:

[image: changed!]

But this does not affect any other users viewing the site unless you have some vulnerability elsewhere.

Comment: @FelixKling join the club ^_^

Comment: @FelixKling booo tinypic is blocked at my office :-(

Comment: Ah well, it's not thaat great anyway... I just took the post and changed some more content...